# Elasticsearch-groovy index template

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

Is there any way to define an index template with the API of elasticsearch-groovy or elasticsearch-java? I want to apply "settings" (custom analyzers) and "mappings" (apply analyzer on fields) on it. The [documentation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-groovy/blob/master/docs/quickstart.asciidoc#create-an-index) only refers to index templatex but does not show a vaild example, how to apply them in a groovy closure. The example shown in the docs, adds the "settings" in the data (source) field.

edit: @Val Thank you for your reply, but if I use the `source` field as follows:

```
    def templateR = client.admin.indices.putTemplate {
        name "template_name"
        source {
            template "template_*"         
        }
    }.actionGet()
```

... this results in a compiler-error: `MissingMethodException No signature of method: ...source()`. The following code:

```
    def templateR = client.admin.indices.putTemplate {
        name "lemato_template"
        template "lemato_*"
        settings {
            number_of_shards= 1      
        }            
    }.actionGet()
```

gives me the compiler error `No such property: number_of_shards`. I'm not sure if I use the [closure delegation](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-groovy/blob/master/docs/enhanced-closures.asciidoc) correctly. Is something like `.asMap()` missing?

Answer (score 2):

elasticsearch-groovy definitely provides support for creating/deleting index templates. The `source` closure may contain anything you can define for [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html). Something like this should work.

```
PutIndexTemplateResponse response = client.admin.indices.putTemplate {
  name "my_template"
  source {
    template "index_*"
    settings {
      index {
        number_of_shards = 5
        number_of_replicas = 1
      }
    }
    mappings {
       // your mapping definitions
    }
    aliases {
       // your aliases
    }
  }
}.actionGet()
```

Comment: Was anything not working? How can I help solve this?